# Swift: "nil while unwrapping an Optional value" that is NOT nil

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsurl, option-type

I have dictionary with `String`'s that are images url's. Compiler throws me an error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I try to create `NSURL` object from this `String`s. I searched that problem and didn't find solution. Everybody said things like "your variable is nil". But my variable can't be nil and my code logs shows that too.

Here's my code:

```
var article: [String:String!]!
...
//viewDidLoad method

let imageURLString : String = article["image"]!

println(imageURLString) // log: http://domain.com/img/path.jpg

let imgURL : NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString(imageURLString) // error here
```

I receives "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Where is the problem? Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NSURL's URLWithString can fail (and so return nil) if the URL is invalid. Try:

```
let imgURL: NSURL? = NSURL.URLWithString(imageURLString)
```

You can then test imgURL to see if it is nil or not before using it.

Comment: This would for example happen if there is a space character or other whitespace before or after `"http://domain.com/img/path.jpg"` (which otherwise looks like a valid URL).

Comment: Thanks you both. The problem was with space character in my XML file. Thanks guys.